# Laravel eloquent relation table prefix

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-5.6

> **Late Comment**
>
> The only way for this to work seems to be defining the foreign key columns in ***table_name_primary_key*** format. If they don't fit this format, the relations simply doesn't work without specifying the column names.

I'm trying to learn how to use foreign keys with the `reliese/laravel` code generator (it's generating models from database), but I have a problem which is forcing me to re-specify all the foreign key names in the generated code. Here's my migration code and the generated relation codes:

**// migration**

```
Schema::create('hotels', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('hotel_id');
    $table->string('name', 64);
    $table->string('description', 512);
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('floors', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('floor_id');
    $table->integer('hotel_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('label', 128);
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('hotel_id')->on('hotels')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**// relation**

```
// Hotel.php contains

public function floors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\Otellier\Floor::class);
}

// Floor.php contains

public function hotel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\Otellier\Hotel::class);
}
```

Now, when I'm creating a floor with Faker:

```
$hotel = factory(App\Hotel::class)->make();
$floor = factory(App\Floor::class)->make([ "label" => "Floor #" . $floor_number ]);
$hotel->floors()->save($floor);
```

In the last line, I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hotel_hotel_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `floors` (`label`, `hotel_hotel_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Floor #1, 8, 2018-03-22 12:37:39, 2018-03-22 12:37:39))

Apparently, it searches for a `hotel_hotel_id` field as a column inside `floors` table, which I suspect is adding the table name as a prefix to the column name. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this and force the whole system not to prefix any column

#### without doing this:

```
public function hotel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\Otellier\Hotel::class, "hotels", "hotel_id", "hotel_id");
}
```

Comment: did you put `hotel_id` in the `$fillable` attributes of you `Floor Model`

Comment: yes it's defined in the model

Comment: laravel usually prefix foreign key with the name of the table on witch you are adding that foreign key

Comment: but the error isn't related to foreign key, it's related to the column name that Laravel is trying to insert data to.

Comment: Do all your models extend `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`? Can you change that?

Comment: Yes they do, no I can't change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel uses `getForiegnKey()` method in **Model.php** to predict the foriegnkey of a relation.

```
/**
 * Get the default foreign key name for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getForeignKey()
{
    return Str::snake(class_basename($this)).'_'.$this->primaryKey;
}
```

You can **override** it in your model or **baseclass** to change it's behaviour. In your case it may be used like,

```
public function getForeignKey()
{
    return $this->primaryKey;
}
```

it will return your `$primaryKey` as the foriegn key when a relation try Io access the correspondent foriegnkey.

NB: If you specify the foriegn key in relation then this method won't work.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to modify the generated model file. This was the closest BTW.

Comment: use a base class and specify the function in it.

Comment: Won't it be still modifying the model file? Sorry, I guess it has no way without modifying any core file or model file.

Answer (score 0):

By default eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the `Floor` model is automatically assumed to have a `hotel_id` foreign key. Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the id (or the custom `$primaryKey`) column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the hotel's `id` column in the `hotel_id` column of the `Floor`.If you would like the relationship to use a value other than `id`, you may pass a third argument to the hasMany method specifying your custom `local key`

```
public function floors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\Otellier\Floor::class, 'hotel_id', 'hotel_id');
}
```

Comment: I asked for a way except modifying the generated classes. Sorry.

Comment: If you think what I'm said is correct and it may useful to anyone, please upvote my answer

Answer (score -1):

You need to define your own primary key in the models:

```
protected $primaryKey='floor_id';
```

and for the other:

```
protected $primaryKey='hotel_id';
```

Comment: Do you have a pivot table?

Comment: Nope, I use pivot tables but this doesn't use one.

Comment: Well, that's the reason it is all messed up. you can try and pass the third argument to those function with the name of the columns you changed.

Comment: No, I use pivot tables for many-to-many relationships. This doesn't need one because it requires one-to-many.